# Query to select from one table and then from the other, based on results

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to select all things from one table and then for each result select from another table only one newest result using MySQL.

The first table is a standard one, with AI id and text name

```
users
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Peter |
+----+-------+
```

then there is the second one with AI id, int user_id, text action and datetime date

```
actions
+----+---------+--------+------------+-----+
| id | user_id | action |    date    | str |
+----+---------+--------+------------+-----+
|  7 |       2 | drink  | 2019-01-10 |   5 |
|  6 |       1 | sleep  | 2019-02-14 |  -2 |
|  5 |       2 | walk   | 2019-04-24 |   4 |
|  4 |       1 | jump   | 2019-03-14 |   3 |
|  3 |       2 | talk   | 2019-04-30 |  -8 |
|  2 |       2 | train  | 2019-04-14 |  -1 |
|  1 |       1 | drive  | 2019-04-01 |   1 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+-----+
```

So now I want to select all from `table_users` and for each found row search `table_actions` and find only newest one, either based on id or date.

So it would look either like this (by id)

```
[0] => ['user_id'] = 1
       ['name'] = John
       ['action'] = sleep
       ['date'] = 2019-02-14
       ['str'] = -2

[1] => ['user_id'] = 2
       ['name'] = Peter
       ['action'] = drink
       ['date'] = 2019-01-10
       ['str'] = 5
```

or like this

```
[0] => ['id'] = 1
       ['name'] = John
       ['table_actions'] => ['id'] = 6
                            ['user_id'] = 1
                            ['action'] = sleep
                            ['date'] = 2019-02-14
                            ['str'] = -2
```

this sounds easy, but I tried few things and nothing worked like this. The closes one was with something like (dont have exact version on my hand, just remembering from on top of my head):

```
SELECT users.*, actions.*
 FROM users
 LEFT JOIN actions ON users.id = (
  SELECT user_id FROM actions
  WHERE users.id = actions.user_id
  LIMIT 1
 )
GROUP BY actions.user_id
```

with that I would get all results from `users` and then for each get one result from `actions`, but that result from `actions` would not be the newest one, apparently it groups as it likes to, I tried MAX(actions.id), but I have got no luck with that.

Does anyone know the solution ? for now I have to take all from `users` and for each result take another query in my php code and I feel there is an elegant and faster way to do that.

Comment: The expected results you posted are inconsistent with: *find only newest one, either based on id or date*

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select 
  user_id,
  max(date) date
from actions
group by user_id
```

you get the latest `date` for each user and then you must join to it the 2 tables:

```
select 
  u.id, u.name, a.id, a.action, a.date, a.str
from users u 
inner join actions a on a.user_id = u.id 
inner join (
  select 
    user_id,
    max(date) date
  from actions
  group by user_id
) g on g.user_id = a.user_id and g.date = a.date
```

If you want the latest results by id and not by date:

```
select 
  u.id, u.name, a.id, a.action, a.date, a.str
from users u 
inner join actions a on a.user_id = u.id 
inner join (
  select 
    user_id,
    max(id) id
  from actions
  group by user_id
) g on g.user_id = a.user_id and g.id = a.id
```

Comment: I cant test it right now (needs to be monday morning), but I trust your answer. Could you please explain how this double inner join works exactly, also what represents the `g`? - the results from second inner join ?

Comment: The first join is between the 2 tables which produces all possible rows for each user and the last join restricts to the rows returned by the subquery which holds only the id of the user and the last date or id. The alias `g` is used to reference the resultset of the subquery, just like the other aliases `u` and `a` are references to the tables.